# How to use grid view and list view in monodroid?

Tags: xamarin.android

How to use grid view and list view in monodroid? give some example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GridView:

http://mono-android.net/Tutorials/Hello_Views/Grid_View

List View:

http://mono-android.net/Tutorials/Hello_Views/List_View

Comment: I think the listview tutorial needs to be updated.  I've tried it with MonoDroid 2.8.2 and it doesn't work for me.  The folder structure in the solution isn't the same as in the tutorial, and the Main.axml is the main entry point and doesn't contain a listview, and the list_view.xml file needs to go into a ListView somehow, but there isn't any such element in the axml referenced in the tutorial.  The tutorial layout is nice and explains it well, but it seems as if it were for a prior version and can't be typed exactly as referenced by that tutorial.

Comment: Are you extending ListActivity instead of Activity?  The tutorial explains that list_view.xml is not for the layout of the screen, but the layout of each list item.  Here's the full code if it helps: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/ApiDemo/Tutorials/ListViewTutorial.cs.